# bash: svn post commit hook adds single quotes to arguments

Tags: bash, shell, svn, trac

I'm trying to create a `post-commit` hook to update trac after a subversion commit.

The hook looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/trac-admin /var/trac/trac-env/ changeset added "$1" "$2"
exit 0
```

(Code is from http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin)

However, when I execute the script manually, I get the following error:

```
./post-commit /var/svn/myrepos 100
*** Unknown syntax: changeset 'added' '/var/svn/myrepos' '100'
```

My question: Where are the single quotes coming from?

Comment: Probably they are part of the error message's formatting and not actually present in the parameters.

Comment: @tripleee You're right. `/usr/bin/trac-admin` is an older version that accepts different arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just error message formatting. See triplee's comment.